# Wifi not working after fresh install ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking

I have old acer aspire 4775G with win 7 in it, since it's to slow to install win 10 and 11, i finally come into linux world because of that ( im new in linux world about 1 month now)

Installing ubuntu linux is easy, but wifi not working..
I try other distro, the result is the same..
I search internet and looks like im not alone.
I end up doing the rfkill guide and other solving guide, but all failed.
I finally make up my mind to comeback to install win 7 again. I make a win 7 flash disk and i install win 7 via the bios...
The bios failed to boot the win 7 flash disk and it automatically boot ubuntu.
The miracle things was, the wifi was working again.
I don't know what happened, but the wifi work's again..

So now, im using now kubuntu and learning arch with manjaro.

I only have to set the win 7 flash disk to boot first before linux boot.

If i don't boot it first, the wifi not working...

Rfkills shows "no" in  that "hard" thing,

I'm sharing this so if someone have the same problem, maybe can try this too..

Or for the experts in here can explain why does it happened

(I make a win 10 flash disk too, it works the same... It can solve my wifi problem too)

Comment: This isn't a Linux support site (SE *Unix & Linux* covers that), but a Ubuntu site specifically. [Kubuntu is a Ubuntu system](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) thus is on-topic here, so what release?  Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices (the ISO you download/install sets the default; inc. for Kubuntu) so please be specific. Did you attempt any troubleshooting (eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide esp. section 3.1 or device recognition is most useful as Linux speaks to the chipset!)